# Unable to debug .class files in IntelliJ. Class files just shows compiled code, code is not visible. IntelliJ Version:2020.1.4

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image]

> Unable to debug inside the .class file. Even after attaching sources, the file is only showing compiled
> code.

Comment: Based on screenshot - it is seen that there are no sources available. How do you add sources? Are there any errors? Do you use Maven/Gradle in project?

Comment: This is an ant project. When attaching sources also, it shows no error..and again shows the same compiled .class file

Comment: What error does it show? Show us the complete error message. Also, the idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) could be useful.

Comment: 2021-02-03 14:10:13,012 [520800225]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Searching for external libraries with Android resources. Found 0 libraries. took 5ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok

Comment: Is the problem only with this jar library? Make sure to try with version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/ If problem remains file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a jar library for which the problem happens and idea.log file after IDE restart and trying to attach scources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet implemented in Intellij.

Include sources or if you have generated classes somewhere you can try adding them to the project.

Refer this for more information -

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206152289-Is-it-possible-to-debug-compiled-classes-instead-of-the-source-

and

- [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83442?_ga=2.59525805.144442511.1653457237-1695572251.1653457237&_gl=1*1hwyj64*_ga*MTY5NTU3MjI1MS4xNjUzNDU3MjM3*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY1MzQ1NzIzNi4xLjEuMTY1MzQ1NzI2OC4w)